# How to create a windows service with credentials in Docker container?

Tags: docker, powershell

I need to start a service in Windows container which has username and password.
In Windows it looks like this:

[image]

In Docker container I tried this:

```
$serviceName = "MyService"
$binaryPath = "c:\MyService.exe"
$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString "MYPASS" -AsPlainText -Force
$mycreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("mydomain\account1", $secpasswd)
New-Service -name $serviceName -binaryPathName $binaryPath -displayName $serviceName -startupType Automatic -credential $mycreds
```

But I get this error:

```
New-Service : Service 'MyService(MyService)' cannot be created due to the following      eerror: The account name is invalid or does not exist, or the password is invalid for the account name specified At line:1 char:1
+ New-Service -name $serviceName -binaryPathName $binaryPath -displayNa ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (MyService:String) [New-Service], ServiceCommandExceptio n
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotNewService,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewServiceCommand
```

I think my domain account credentials aren't somehow reachable in docker container.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use group managed service accounts.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/manage-containers/manage-serviceaccounts